# About Tomcat as httpServer

Tags: web-server, tomcat

I'd like to know if it is possible to configure (and if yes: how) Tomcat acting like http web server without using Apache isapi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat is a servlet container which also serves web applications on http/https protocol. So in it's default avatar, any web app deployed on Tomcat runs on the defined port (default 8080
) and thus Tomcat is acting as a web server.

You dont need Apache to front it for static content. Just drop your webapp into TOMCAT_HOME/webapps and start the Tomcat server.

Access it on `http://localhost:8080/<webapp>`

Comment: Just another question: I heard about a security risk in doing this. Is it true?

Comment: Not really, the latest Tomcats are quite stable and secure. Read this http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/03/24/myth-or-truth-one-should-always-use-apache-httpd-front-apache-tomcat-improve-perform article too